# Java integer pair in set

Tags: java

```
private HashSet<Coords> pairs = new HashSet<Coords>();

private class Coords {

    int x;
    int z;

    Coords(int x, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
    }

}
```

How can I check if the HashSet contains a set of two x,y coordinates? The following is not working.

```
pairs.contains(new Coords(x, z));
```

Comment: what key, its a HashSet not a HashMap?

Comment: You need to override `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: So would storing a hashset of integers then checking the hashcode be better?

Comment: No, as **QBrute** said just override `hashCode()` and `equals()` for your `Coords` class and it will work.

Comment: @STaefi Why do I need to override hashcode and not just equals() ?

Comment: Nevermind. i read the other question